# String replace without replacing the first instance

Tags: python

I have a string and I want to replace `the` every time after its second occurrence only.

```
s = "change the string in the sentence and the save"
```

I would like the replace the word `the` to `hello`. But except the first one.

Output should be:

```
change the string in hello sentence and hello save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def replace_not_first(str, word, replace):
    str_arr = str.split(word)
    return str_arr[0] + word + replace.join(str_arr[1:])

str = "change the string in the sentence and the save"
print(replace_not_first(str, 'the', 'hello'))
```

prints: `change the string in hello sentence and hello save`

Answer (score 3):

I would split the string from right with the word you're going to replace use [`str.rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) function, but only split [`s.count('the') - 1`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) times.

Then, join the output list with `hello`:

```
>>> s.rsplit('the', s.count('the') - 1)
['change the string in ', ' sentence and ', ' save']

>>> 'hello'.join(s.rsplit('the', s.count('the') - 1))
'change the string in hello sentence and hello save'
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
string = "change the string in the sentence and the save"
the_arr = string.split("the")
print the_arr[0] + "the" + "hello".join(the_arr[1:])`
```

Comment: I don't want to change the first one value. i need to change from the second one itself

Comment: This does not work if `**hello**` is already in the string and is located before the first `the`. Such as: `**hello** change the string in the sentence and the save`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following one liner solution.

```
string = 'change the string in the sentence and the save'
new_string = string[:string.find('the')+3] + string[string.find('the')+3:].replace('the', 'hello')
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will do the job.

```
str = str.partition('the')[0] + str.partition('the')[1] + str.partition('the')[-1].replace('the','hello')
```

Comment: `str.partition('the')` needs to go through the whole text and your code is wastefully doing it three times.

Comment: Do: `first, the, rest = str.partition('the'); str = first + the + rest.replace('the', 'hello')`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> str = "change the string in the sentence and the save"
>>> str.replace('the', 'hello')
>>> str.replace('hello', 'the',1)
```

Comment: I guess this is not correct way. coz what if the sentence is like "hello change the string in the sentence and the save". your code will replace 1st hello which is in original string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> s = "change the string in the sentence and the save"
>>> s.split("the",1)[0]+"the" + s.split("the",1)[1].replace("the","hello")
'change the string in hello sentence and hello save'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into parts:

```
string = "change the string in the sentence and the save"

splitString = string.split()
firstIndex = splitString.index('the')

part1 = ' '.join(splitString[:firstIndex+1])
part2 = ' '.join(splitString[firstIndex+1:]).replace('the','hello')

newString = part1 + ' ' + part2
```

Or in one line:

```
newString = ' '.join(['hello' if j == 'the' and i != string.split().index('the') else j for i, j in enumerate(string.split())])
```